# TaffyDB OR operator how to?

Tags: jquery, json, operator-keyword, taffydb

From a JSON file, I want to select all book with title="hello" and priced at 50 or published in year 2010.

I am not able to figure out how to the OR logical operator.

I have done something like this, using ||, but I don't think it's the right thing.

Code:

```
    var query = new TAFFY(json);

    query({Title:"hello"},{Price:"50"}||{Year:"2010"}).each(function (r) {  

     --- do Something

    });
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 3):

try this query:

```
query({Title:"hello"},[{Price:"50"},{Year:"2010"}])
```

from taffyDB page:

```
// does a match for column that is one of two values
db([{column:"value"},{column:"value2"}]);

// Real world example - records with a status of active or pending
db([{status:"Active"},{status:"Pending"}]);
```